# SQL - Copying certain rows in a table to the same table and changing their values

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have the following table in Microsoft SQL Server called CustomerInfo

BEFORE

```
CustomerInfo

Type         CustomerId          CustParameter        Value
Inbound      StateLOCAL          LastName             Johnson
Inbound      StateLOCAL          ExchangeCode         ALI
Inbound      StateLOCAL          IsPriority           False
Inbound      CityLOCAL           LastName             Rogers
Inbound      CityLOCAL           ExchangeCode         RAR
Inbound      CityLOCAL           IsPriority           True
Inbound      TownBOUND           LastName             Brown
Inbound      TownBOUND           ExchangeCode         JSP
Inbound      TownBOUND           IsPriority           True
```

And I need to get it to the following table

AFTER

```
CustomerInfo

Type         CustomerId          CustParameter        Value
Inbound      StateLOCAL          LastName             Johnson
Inbound      StateLOCAL          ExchangeCode         ALI
Inbound      StateLOCAL          IsPriority           False
Inbound      CityLOCAL           LastName             Rogers
Inbound      CityLOCAL           ExchangeCode         RAR
Inbound      CityLOCAL           IsPriority           True
Inbound      TownBOUND           LastName             Brown
Inbound      TownBOUND           ExchangeCode         JSP
Inbound      TownBOUND           IsPriority           True
Inbound      CityBORDER          LastName             Rogers
Inbound      CityBORDER          ExchangeCode         RAR
Inbound      CityBORDER          IsPriority           True
```

The table is a lot bigger and I need it to do the following:

- If the CustomerId column contains the word 'LOCAL' in it and if the CustParameter column contains the word 'IsPriority' AND the Value column contains the word 'True'
- Then the 3 records that have the same CustomerId needs to be copied back into the same table BUT the word LOCAL in the CustomerId column needs to be changed to the word BORDER so for example CityLOCAL becomes CityBORDER when it is copied.

Comment: Is this MySql or SQL Server?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these SQL.

step1: Execute below SQL. Result is OK.

```
select Type,  REPLACE(ci.CustomerID, 'LOCAL', 'BORDER'), CustParameter, Value from customerInfo where customerId in (
select distinct CustomerId from customer_info where CustomerId like "%LOCAL%" and CustParameter = "IsPriority" and Value= "True"
```

)

step2: Execute below SQL. insert that record in to table.

```
INSERT INTO customerInfo (Type, CustomerId, CustParameter, Value)
    select Type, REPLACE(ci.CustomerID, 'LOCAL', 'BORDER'), CustParameter, Value from customerInfo where customerId in (
    select distinct CustomerId from customer_info where CustomerId like "%LOCAL%" and CustParameter = "IsPriority" and Value= "True"

    )
```

Thank you.

Comment: From the first step it saysColumn 'Type' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE
  ci
SET
  ci.CustomerID = REPLACE(ci.CustomerID, 'LOCAL', 'BORDER')
FROM
  CustomerInfo ci
WHERE
  ci.CustomerID IN ( SELECT DISTINCT
                      ci2.CustomerID
                     WHERE
                      ci2.CustomerID LIKE '%LOCAL%'
                      AND ci2.CustParameter LIKE '%IsPriority%'
                      AND ci2.Value = 'True' )
```